# Nfca empty card crashes NFC

Tags: android, tags, nfc, samsung-mobile

I am currently developing an Android application to communicate with Nfca (14443 type A) cards but when I am touching my Samsung Galaxy S II plus to an empty nfca card, it looks like the tag keeps on disconnecting and reconnecting to my device (even with no application open) and after a short time it crashes the NFC on the smartphone meaning i can't read any kind of tags.

This problem does not occur on a Samsung Galaxy S III which is able to correctly connect to the tag and communicate with it successfully. 
Same result with a usb contactless smart card reader and a software on my PC, everything works fine.

Is there a different NFC reader in the different android devices or what can explain such behavior on my S II plus ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide information on what version of Android these devices run?

Comment: both devices are running 4.1.2

Comment: This seems like a software issue or a hardware issue; not a programming issue.